# How to pass result from one selector to another with NgRx

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have the following selector I want it to return sorted and filtered list.

```
export const selectSortedAndFilteredDataServices = (
    selectProperties: SelectProperties,
): MemoizedSelector<AppState, DataService[], DefaultProjectorFn<DataService[]>> =>
    createSelector(
        selectDataServices,
        selectSortedDataServices(selectProperties.sort),
        selectFilteredDataServices(selectProperties.filter),
        (state: DataServiceState) => state.dataServices,
    );
```

I expected `selectSortedDataServices` selector to pass its result from to the next selector, however at each step the child selectors are sorting and filtering the original list.

What do I need to change so that result from each selector is passed to the next selector?

Answer (score 1):

That is not the way, how the createSelector function works.

PseudoCode:

```
const mySelector = createSelector(
    selector1,
    selector2,
    selector3,
    (selector1Result, selector2Result, selector3Result) => //your sort and filter logic
)
```

So, with that in mind, you can build a service, which maps and filters the result, or you can combine different selectors to split you logic:

```
const selectDataServices = createSelector(...)

const selectSortedDataServices = (selectProperties: SelectProperties) => createSelector(
    selectDataServices,
    (services) => //your sort logic

const selectFilteredDataServices = (selectProperties: SelectProperties) => createSelector(
    selectSortedDataServices,
    (services) => //your filter logic
)
```

By the way, I would not use properties or selector factories with properties, because then you lose the selector caching (memoizing). Everything you need at this point should be allready in the state.

Comment: I figure it would be something like that, so I did opt to do sort and filtering like the pseudo code you wrote. I just had to have someone tell me so :)

But if you don't suggest to use factory functions, then how would I pass the sort and filtering properties required for my selectors?

Comment: It depends :) If you use the result in the view, I would just create a simple selector and use a pipe in the ngFor loop. Or if you want to persist the options (sort/filter), then you could persist them in the state and select them, when needed.

Comment: you mean you would do the sort and filtering on view rather than doing it with a selector?

Comment: I don't mean, that mapping in the selector is bad. It depends on the scenario. Does your view change while selecting another filter? Or do you need a static list, which needs to be filtered one time? Should the logic be sharable? ...

Comment: yes, the filter and sorting would happen based on the sort and filter properties passed to the selector. so it can happen one or more times. the selector itself is going to be used at least in two places so yea, the logic will be shared as well.

Comment: Then I would add the sort and filter options as siblings to the entities in the entityState and combine them in the selectors. That gives the posibility to reuse the state on different views without readjust them (as a user). That's not allways the desired beheaviour, but its possible in that way.